# How to set the decimal place of a DataGridTextColumn programmatically?

Tags: wpf, datatable, datagrid, decimal

I am adding the columns to a DataGrid through the following code:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "n", Binding = new Binding("n") { StringFormat = "{0:n2}" } });
```

The data I am binding to is a DataTable retrieved from a database. The value in the DataTable is of type money in the database, thus when displayed in the DataGrid the values would be something like 1000.0000.

What is the StringFormat set to in order to remove the decimal places because **StringFormat = "{0:n2}"** does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :
`Binding = new Binding("n") { StringFormat = "{0,1:F4}" } });`